# Boundary condition of gravitational potential

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, computational-physics, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

I solve a system of coupled equations numerically. One of the most important, is equation of the gravitational potential,
$$\nabla^2 \phi = 4\pi G m \rho(r)$$
But I have physical problem with boundary condition, I take
$$\nabla \phi(0) =-\infty $$
I want to know if I can take this boundary condition or not?

Comment: no, because any n times infinity is still infinity

Comment: The boundary condition doesn’t make sense because the left side is a vector and the right side isn’t.

Comment: If $\rho$ is sufficiently localized, you typically rather take $\phi(\infty)=0$

Answer (score 1):

For the gravitational potential, one does not expect an infinite acceleration (recall that $\mathbf{F}=-m\nabla\phi$ implies that $-\nabla\phi=\mathbf{g}$) at the center of the object. Instead, one would expect an acceleration of zero,
$$\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{n}=0$$
on the boundary $\partial\Omega$.

Since you mentioned solving it numerically, and assuming that you are using finite differences for solving this PDE, you would simply set your ghost cells at $r=0$ to be equal to the value of the cells just outside $r=0$ such that taking a finite difference at the boundary would return 0 (cf. [this Math.se answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2920625)),
$$0=\frac{u_{-1}-u_{1}}{2\Delta x}\implies u_{-1}=u_1.$$